# Flutter webapp redirects to homepage

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

I've created single page webapp (Not connected to database, currently using hardcoded dummy data)

when I deploy it on independent server it works fine (i.e [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) but when I deploy it as a sub-app ([www.example.com/flutter](http://www.example.com/flutter)) it redirects to home page ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)), not considering relative url.

I haven't setup any navigation/routing in that since it is single page app and does not contain much data.

Answer (score 0):

If your Web App needs to use a relative path for the base URL of the app, just find the  tag in the index.html (inside of the web folder) and change the base path.

In your case, you would just change the base path to: `<base href="/flutter/">`

After that, in subsequent web builds the base path of your app will be assumed to `www.example.com/flutter`.